# Add argument To event handler.

Tags: c#, event-handling

well i have this code.

```
recognizer.SpeechRecognized +=
                      new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);


 static void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result != null && e.Result.Text != null)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("  Recognized text =  {0}", e.Result.Text);
                File.WriteAllText("text/text.txt", e.Result.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Recognized text not available.");
            }
        }
```

i want to add a parameter to be added in my code say myData to be showed in the function so that i may print that too with the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify the method to accept the argument(s) that you will actually need:

```
static void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(
    SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e, string myData)
```

Then use a lambda to assign the event handler, pass along the appropriate arguments, and close over whatever data you have:

```
string myData = "hello world";
recognizer.SpeechRecognized += 
    (s, args) => recognizer_SpeechRecognized(args, myData);
```

Comment: please elaborate. i am new to c#

Comment: @Adeel What elaboration do you need?  What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: the second part where i assign the lambda to assign the event handler.

Comment: i mean how will i pass this new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>

Comment: @Adeel I showed you exactly how.  The code that I provided is literally, exactly, character for character, the code that you would need to attach a new event handler to this event that calls your method.  The use of `new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>` will be inferred; it is entirely redundant to state it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider having `myData` as a field in the class which has this handler. And make this handler non-static.

I wouldn't suggest hacking your way around and passing `myData` with handler.

Comment: There may well be a sensible reason for the method to be static.  Perhaps the event handler is also attached from a static context.  This also creates a variable that the programmer needs to be concerned about being manipulated from any other places throughout the class, rather than limiting its scope to only those places where it is needed.  Finally, passing the data directly, rather than creating a field, is easier to program, in no way a hack, is better design, easier to code, and more effective.